# Oracle plsql procedure not override

Tags: plsql

I'm new to pl/sql. I created a procedure with name as PROC1 and if another person creating procedure with same name and my procedure wil get override. is there any solution not to override my procedure proc1 with same name ??

Comment: usally functions/procedures are grouped by a package. In addition to that, you can use schemas to separate user procedures/data

Answer (score 0):

Things to note:

1. If a procedure named `PROC1` exists in your schema, no other procedure/function can be named as `PROC1` in your schema. One can create a package with the same name though, and inside it they can create functions/procedures with name `PROC1`.
2. If there is a public synonym named `PROC1` in some other user's schema and you specify `PROC1`, `CALL PROC1`, etc., your own procedure will be called instead of the other. If they make a call to `PROC1`, they will access their own object, instead of your procedure.
3. A call to the procedure does not alter it. One must use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1` in your schema to replace it with their version.

Answer (score 0):

If the person creates the procedure suing "create procedure ..." then they'll get a warning, of course, whereas "create or replace procedure ..." will not raise an error. So yes,

Standalone procedures share a namespace with Tables, Views, Sequences, Private synonyms, Stand-alone procedures, Stand-alone stored functions, Packages, Materialized views, and User-defined types, so a pre-existing object with the same name of any of those types will prevent a function being created.

That's not normally a problem though and doesn't require that people prefix object names with TAB or FNC or anything, as a well-constructed name for these objects generally points to the type of object it is -- eg. USERS (plural noun -> table), CREATE_INVOICE (ACTION + NOUN -> procedure), ACTIVE_USERS (adjective + noun -> view)

It could be that you have multiple procedures with the same name but different specifications, though, and they can happily co-exist if they're defined in a package. There are strong arguments for all procedures to exist as part of a package, not standalone.